# How can I search a value in two different dataframes and add it to a third one?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe in which I want to find a client number that can be in two either of two different dataframes. My question is, how can I make it in a fast way, rather than merge both dataframes and after asking which one is null and not usefeul.

```
df0

ClientName     City         State
JohnSmith      Dallas         TX
JaneDoe        Dallas         TX
LucasAult      Dallas         TX
CarsonSeibert  Dallas         TX
```

df1 to be looked

```
ClientName     CLientNumber
JohnSmith      100
JaneDoe        101
```

df2 to be looked

```
ClientName     CLientNumber
LucasAult        102
CarsonSeibert    103
```

Expected Result

```
ClientName     City         State   ClientNumber
JohnSmith      Dallas         TX       100
JaneDoe        Dallas         TX       101
LucasAult      Dallas         TX       102
CarsonSeibert  Dallas         TX       103
```

so far my proposed solution is this

```
df0 = pd.merge(df0, df1, how ='left')
df0 = pd.merge(df0, df2, how ='left')

df0['ClientNumber'] = np.where(df0['ClientNumber'] == None, df1['ClientNumber'], df0['ClientNumber'])
```

Comment: You could concatenate `df1` and `df2` and do a single merge.

Comment: also, `df0['ClientNumber'] == None` doesn't do any good, always returns `False`. Use `df0['ClientNumber'].isna()`.

Comment: You can follow the section on how to merge multiple dataframes in the dupe

Comment: Actually I was rereading that section and agree with you that the current approach of concat with merge is much simpler for this case @ALollz reopened

Answer (score 3):

You can simply **[concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)** `df1`,`df2` and then perform a **[merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)** with `df0`

```
df0.merge(pd.concat([df1,df2]), on='ClientName')
```

Output:

```
ClientName     City         State   ClientNumber
JohnSmith      Dallas         TX       100
JaneDoe        Dallas         TX       101
LucasAult      Dallas         TX       102
CarsonSeibert  Dallas         TX       103
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` is good enough with a join on one unique key:

```
d = {**df1.set_index('ClientName').CLientNumber, 
     **df2.set_index('ClientName').CLientNumber}

df0['ClientNumber'] = df0['ClientName'].map(d)
```

---

```
      ClientName    City State  ClientNumber
0      JohnSmith  Dallas    TX           100
1        JaneDoe  Dallas    TX           101
2      LucasAult  Dallas    TX           102
3  CarsonSeibert  Dallas    TX           103
```